# Use Stack Overflow's authentication API in a browser extension

Tags: support, oauth2, apps, authentication

I want to create a browser extension that reproduce the Stack Overflow navbar (inbox and achievements):

[image: Stack Overflow navbar]

I need for that to authenticate the current user using the [authentication API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

For this step, I need to provide a `redirect_uri` parameter that *must be under an app's registered domain*. It is used to redirected the user when he/she logged in.

My issue is that browser extensions don't have a URL (it's just like a local web application). So how can I log a user in a browser extension using the API?